# why this happned I'm going to use the module HTMLParser

Tags: python

Link.finder.py has:

```
import HTMLParser
from urlparse import urlparse

class LInkFinder(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print(tag)

    def error(self, message):
        pass


finder = LInkFinder()
finder.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sijier/PycharmProjects/day1/link_finder.py", line 4, in <module>
    class LInkFinder(HTMLParser):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Should I must use **init** in pyhon version 2.7?
What is problem here? And why?
  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this code. The initial one is that you try to subclass the HTMLParser *module*, not the *class* that that module contains. You should do:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
```

Once you've fixed that, you will find problems in your `__init__` method; you can't just reference `super` like that without calling it, and in Python 2 you need to pass the current class and the self instance there. But in fact there is no point in defining a method just to call the superclass version; you should delete that `__init__` definition altogether.

Comment: It works, but there is going noting. What is the problems now?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: That ALL right, I wrok it our with your help, thanks a lot. :)